# TypeScript error with jQueryUI AutoComplete in VS2015

Tags: jquery-ui, typescript, visual-studio-2015, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 2, and regularly getting a TypeScript error when building the solution for a client's system. The particular error is:

```
TS2345 Argument of type
    '{
        source: (req: any, resp: any) => void;
        focus: (event: any, ui: any) => void;
        minLength: number;
        ...'
    is not assignable to parameter of type 'AutocompleteOptions'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'focus' does not exist
    in type 'AutocompleteOptions'.
```

Having looked at the [jQueryUI documentation for autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus), this appears to be legitimate.

The fragment of code causing this error (from within an `init()` function) is as follows:

```
$(lookupElem).autocomplete({
    source: (req, resp) => this.onAutoCompleteRequest(req, resp),
    focus: (event, ui) => {
        // Don't populate input field with selected value (pxid)
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    minLength: 3,  // Don't call autocomplete until specified number of characters have been input
    select: (e, ui) => this.onItemSelected(e, ui)
});
```

This has worked in VS2013, so I'm not sure why VS2015 is having an issue. This is causing the rest of the solution (e.g. Azure components, separate MVC website) to fail the build, plus it's deleting the existing `.js` and `.js.map` files from my source folder.

How can I either:

- fix this; or
- suppress this error completely from Visual Studio?

My version of the TypeScript tools is **1.8.24.0**, which appears to be up-to-date from within Tools => Extensions and Updates.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This has worked in VS2013, so I'm not sure why VS2015 is having an issue

This is because of a new feature of `freshness` in TypeScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html

## Quick Fix

Just move to a variable:

```
const config = {
    source: (req, resp) => this.onAutoCompleteRequest(req, resp),
    focus: (event, ui) => {
        // Don't populate input field with selected value (pxid)
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    minLength: 3,  // Don't call autocomplete until specified number of characters have been input
    select: (e, ui) => this.onItemSelected(e, ui)

};
$(lookupElem).autocomplete(config);
```

## Better Fix

Send a PR to definitely typed

Comment: Great, it worked - thanks for that! Can you please clarify the "Better fix"? Based on the Freshness article, I'm guessing there would need to be some TypeScript type binding for autoComplete options to include `[x: string]: any` so that optional properties are allowed.

Comment: @d_mcg no. You need to add `focus:any` on the type that the `complete` method accepts